# How to set useragent for phantomjs in serenity-bdd?

Tags: serenity-bdd

how do we set a user-agent for phantomjs in serenity-bdd ? 
for ex: I want to write automated tests for mobile-site. In this case, how do i provide phantomjs a mobile user-agent ?

Or is there another way to test mobile site thru serenity-bdd ? Not on real devices though. I specifically want mobile-site tested

Answer (score 0):

How would you do this in native WebDriver?